# How can we better promote this site?

Tags: discussion

A lot of developer/general questions are asked & answered on telegram and/or other social media where they get buried and/or repeated. While the answers/feedback may be quicker, they aren't preserved in a user-friendly way.

I realize those that aren't previously familiar with Stack Overflow (non-developers or otherwise), first-time developers directly entering the eosio space, and the eosio community in general, may not necessarily be aware of this site.

How can we improve visibility and encourage users to utilize this site?

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy to push another round of promotion from Block.one's side - what angle would you like us to take?

Comment: Possibly linking the site where/when appropriate, maybe tweeting relevant unanswered questions would draw attention as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

1. If a question is asked on Telegram or social media, do not answer directly, but link to the corresponding answer on Stack Overflow. If the question is not on Stack Overflow, then encourage the people who would usually answer inline to write the question and answer together on here.
2. Link to the Stack Overflow website directly in these channels. Have a pinned message indicating that this website exists and encouraging users to sign up to it.

Comment: That's a solid approach.